# jquery remove and add class in list element

Tags: jquery, menu, toggle

i have this jquery code to toggle (remove class from li element and in another) in my menu automatically from jquery code

```
<div id='menu'>
<ul>
<li><a href="index.php" class="active">item 1</a></li>
<li><a href="about.php">item 2</a></li>                
<li><a href="contact.php" class="lastmenu">item 3</a></li>            
</ul>
</div>
```

and the jquery code i tried

```
$("#menu li a").click(function() {
    debugger;
  $("#menu li a").not(this).removeClass("active");
  $(this).toggleClass("active");
});
```

but this doesn't seem to do any class adding and removing.
what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Looks like you are redirecting to a new page... so the state updated here will be lost

Comment: add `return false` to the end of your henadler

Comment: also have you actually got a #menu id anywhere?

Comment: @DarrenCrabb yes, pls look at the code, i updated it

Comment: The main problem is as Arun suggested, you are loading a new page and this data will not hold over a page load. It looks like you'll have to do this backend or on page load. But even if you were preventing the page load, your current JS would remove an active class from a link if you click on the already active link.

Comment: @smerny i noticed that, but don't know how to solve it

Comment: @ArunPJohny yes that true, any suggestion pls.

Comment: in that case you need to set the active state based on the current page href

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are dealing with pages which are reloaded you can try

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    var path = location.pathname.split('/').pop();
    $('#menu li a[href="' + path + '"]').addClass('active');
})
```

Comment: thanks. this worked, i added these two lines in document ready at the bottom of every page `var path = location.pathname.split('/').pop();
    $('#menu li a[href="' + path + '"]').addClass('active');`

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
   $("#menu li a").click(function() {
      $("#menu li a").removeClass("active");
      $(this).addClass("active");
    });
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LLaG3/)

Comment: As mention by others, am loading a new page on click

Comment: @grigno, your fiddle links to `#` which doesn't cause a page load. The OP's real problem is that he is loading a new page on click, so any changes to the dom would be lost.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var page = window.location.href;
page = (page.split("/").pop()).split(".php")[0]+".php";
$("#menu li a.active").removeClass("active");
$("#menu li a[href='"+page+"']").addClass("active");
```

[**Fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/7AVux/2)

Comment: This would prevent the page from loading which I am positive is not what the OP wants.

Comment: @smerny, yes go with arun's suggestion.